# How to display files that are not in a project in VisualStudio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just noticed that the logs created by Serilog automagically show up in the solution explorer.

Is there a way to have this work for other files that are also not explicitly part of the project?

For instance, appsettings.*.json?

[image: Solution Explorer panel in VS2022]

Looking at various forums, including this one, I've not found anything.

---

EDIT UPDATE:

I don't want to specifically add AppSettings.development.json to the project as that will now create a git file change. I'm looking for something like a .suo or other setting that will allow the project to display files that only I'm interested in. I don't want to pollute the code base with my version of appsettings.development.json.

---

EDIT UPDATE, UPDATE:

It's close~ish. The context menu for appsettings.json shows a list of files in its directory, and among them is appsettings.development.json.

[image: Context Menu]

---

ANSWERED:

It was inside the explorer the whole time.

[image: Expand AppSettings.json]

Comment: When I add files (*.json, *.txt, *.bmp, *.zip, even Open Office files) in the project folder in Windows Explorer then these files are automatically comes to the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin, yes, adding files to the project does indeed cause them to display in the solution explorer. However, the Log20240213.log was NOT added to the project, and yet it DOES display in the solution explorer. I want something like that for my appsettings.development.json, so that I can get to it easier, but it should not be part of the project itself.

Comment: I think `appsettings.development.json` is already there. If you click on the triangle next to `appsettings.json` it should expand showing the related files. For "showing other file not in the project" - just turn "Show all files" option.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik, yep, there it is. All I had to do was click on the triangle.